# SPFx development - npm audit vulnerabilities

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, nodejs, npm, yeoman-generator

The company I work for needs custom web parts in modern SharePoint.

I was humming along following the excellent (Microsoft's sponsored) tutorials on SPFx development.  I got my web part working on my DEV tenant and all that.

Now that I am getting things ready for production **I am shocked** to find the out-of-the-box vulnerabilities introduced by `yo @microsoft/sharepoint` are not that easy to fix. I need to go through each package **one by one**.

Am I missing something? I am seeking latest guidance on how to address the vulnerabilities. I am new to this tool set.

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share what vulnerabilities you are concerned about, or a link to where you found these vulnerabilities documented.  Your statement is a little too vague for anyone to address.

Comment: Thank you @willman The following modules are reported from "npm audit":             "module_name": "minimatch",
 "url": "https://npmjs.com/advisories/118"
 
 "module_name": "fresh",
 "url": "https://npmjs.com/advisories/526"
 
 "module_name": "lodash",
 "url": "https://npmjs.com/advisories/782"
 
 "module_name": "qs",
 "url": "https://npmjs.com/advisories/1469"
 
 MODERATE:
 
  "module_name": "mime",
  "url": "https://npmjs.com/advisories/535"
  
  "module_name": "serialize-javascript",
  "url": "https://npmjs.com/advisories/1426"

Comment: Which versions of yeoman and SPFx are you using?

Comment: The advisories recommend fixing the versions.  Problem is that above mentioned packages are dependencies of many others.  If in the json manifest I see dependencies that that have too old version of the problem package.  Example: Recommendation to upgrade 'minimatch' to  version '3.0.2' or greater .   Some versions used are '2.0.1' .  This will cause a break in functionality if I change to '3.0.2'.  Therefore it means I will have to fix the affected package code manually.

Comment: @willman, I got these versions:  +-- @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.10.0
`-- yo@3.1.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With SPFx solutions, none of the `npm` *packages* are deployed to SharePoint, so you can ignore these audit warnings. If you had a custom solution that did deploy the `npm` packages themselves, yes you'd need to address it.

[Don't be alarmed by vulnerabilities after running NPM Install](https://www.voitanos.io/blog/don-t-be-alarmed-by-vulnerabilities-after-running-npm-install)

Comment: Thanks @trevorseward for sharing the article. All I am doing is pulling one of the wonderful web parts from https://sharepoint.github.io/sp-dev-fx-webparts/samples/all/   This web part will go to production very much as is.    I did run the 'npm install' on the folder which brought the audit report same as in 'yeoman @microsoft/sharepoint'